# Large Input text file with two numbers each line, how to take input faster?

Tags: c++

I have a text file with format as below-

1 2

3 4

5 6

So on till 5 mil lines.I am taking the input using this code-

```
ifstream fin;
fin.open("abc.txt");
while(!fin.eof()){
    fin>>vert>>adj;
    cout<<vert << "  "<<adj;

}
```

The program is taking around 15 min to process the input. Is there any way to speed up the processing.

Comment: How large is the file, how many resources do you have (does it fit in RAM?) and why do you `cout` all the stuff? Your program might run in a fraction of the time if you skipped the console output.

Comment: The console output will massivley slow down your program. `cout` is pretty expensive.

Comment: Yes, file is 60mb and I have 8gb ram. I cout to see that program is executing correctly.

Comment: Incidentally, it isn't. See [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition considered wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong)

Answer (score 1):

You're most likely using a debug build or a very bad implementation of the standard library. Note:

1. Writing to a file is usually faster than writing to `cout`.
2. Using `std::endl` forces a file flush, and is thus very slow. Don't do that, instead output a newline `'\n'`.
3. The `while(! fin.eof())` is [**wrong**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5605125/1329652). Never do that.

Here are my results:

```
Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.57) (based on LLVM 3.5svn)

t1=3.00009s
t2=10.9166s
t3=18.1806s
```

Test case:

```
// https://github.com/KubaO/stackoverflown/tree/master/questions/ios-timing-40304260
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
using namespace std;

int main() {
   const int N = 5000000;
   const char kFile1[] = "tmp1.txt", kFile2[] = "tmp2.txt";

   auto start = chrono::system_clock::now();
   {
      ofstream fOut;
      fOut.open(kFile1);
      for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
         // !! DO NOT use endl here!
         fOut << i-N << ' ' << N-i << '\n';
   }
   auto t1 = chrono::system_clock::now();
   cerr << "t1=" << chrono::duration<double>(t1-start).count() << "s" << endl;

   double vert, adj;

   {
      ifstream fIn;
      ofstream fOut;
      fIn.open(kFile1);
      fOut.open(kFile2);
      while (fIn >> vert && fIn >> adj)
         // !! DO NOT use endl here!
         fOut << vert << ' ' << adj << '\n';
   }
   auto t2 = chrono::system_clock::now();
   cerr << "t2=" << chrono::duration<double>(t2-t1).count() << "s" << endl;

   {
      ifstream fIn;
      fIn.open(kFile1);
      while (fIn >> vert && fIn >> adj)
         // !! DO NOT use endl here!
         cout << vert << ' ' << adj << '\n';
   }
   auto t3 = chrono::system_clock::now();
   cerr << "t3=" << chrono::duration<double>(t3-t2).count() << "s" << endl;
}
```